# Exceptions when using IOBluetoothHostController.default()

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth

I'm using the [`IOBluetooth` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth) in a macOS command line tool (macOS 10.13.4, XCode 9.3). My application works as expected, but emits error messages regarding exceptions to standard error when I call `IOBluetoothHostController.default()`.

Given the following code:

```
import Foundation
import IOBluetooth

if let controller = IOBluetoothHostController.default() {
    if controller.powerState.rawValue == 1 {
        print("Bluetooth is on")
    } else {
        print("Bluetooth is off")
    }
} else {
    print("Can't get Bluetooth host controller")
}
```

I get the following output:

```
$ ./btsimple
2018-04-25 15:06:05.098 btsimple[10756:673370] Exception NSInvalidArgumentException thrown while decoding IOBluetoothSDPServiceRecord
2018-04-25 15:06:05.099 btsimple[10756:673370] Exception NSInvalidArgumentException thrown while decoding IOBluetoothSDPServiceRecord
Bluetooth is on
$
```

Why are these error messages being logged? Do I need to somehow set up an SDP service record before calling `IOBluetoothHostController.default()`?